# Achievement.getRevealedImageUri() load the icon instead of the progress for incremental achievements

Tags: android, google-play-games, achievements

I have created a game where I need to display the achievements in a custom UI.
When I try to get the ImageUri, I am expecting to get the progress circle that we can see in Play Games application, and not the icon.

Is there a trick or a parameter to get the progress circle for incremental achievements?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the progress circle image from the `Achievement` directly, you must use `currentSteps` and `totalSteps` from the `Achievement` object to get the progress value.

To create the progress circle, you can use a `ProgressBar`. You will set the `progressBar.max` property to `totalSteps` and the `progressBar.progress` property to `currentSteps`.